Do you have to Apple ID verify every time for Among Us, or is this a glitch for me?
I play Among Us mobile, and it seems as if I have to Face ID / Enter Apple ID Password every time to "verify Apple ID". Is this a regular symptom for Among Us (and if so, why not just one initial verification?) or is this a glitch for me?
